# Find a value in a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let:

```
M = [{'name': 'john', 'result': 12}, 
     {'name': 'sara', 'result': 20}, 
     {'name': 'karl', 'result': 11}]
```

If I want to find Sara's result, I thought about:

```
 M[[m['name'] for m in M].index('sara')]['result']     # hard to read, but works
```

and

```
[m['result'] for m in M if m['name'] == 'sara'][0]     # better
```

**Is there an even more natural way to do this in Python?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a generator with `next()`.

```
next(m['result'] for m in L if m['name'] == 'sara')
```

Comment: Just to be sure to understand, this is to avoid `[...][0]`, is it a better practice?

Comment: Yes - the advantage is that it stops iterating as soon as a match is found, and doesn't construct an unnecessary list.

Comment: add a default `None` second parameter to return `None` instead of `StopIteration` exception

Answer (score 3):

If you have several lookups to perform, linear search isn't the best option.

Rebuild a dictionary once with the proper key (name):

```
M = [{'name': 'john', 'result': 12},
     {'name': 'sara', 'result': 20},
     {'name': 'karl', 'result': 11}]

newdict = {d["name"] : d["result"] for d in M}
```

It creates:

```
{'john': 12, 'karl': 11, 'sara': 20}
```

now when you need the result from a name, just do:

```
print(newdict.get('sara'))
```